# Customize the email subject and body in Spring boot admin alert

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I am using spring boot admin to monitor the spring boot applications and configured the default email notification properties of spring boot with default email template.
Is there any way we can customize the email body? I came across a few posts on the internet about custom email templates but did not get any reference example.
It would be a great help if anyone has done the same and share any reference.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [customizing mail template](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/784).